# Make a custom error page in localhost ID asp.net

Tags: asp.net, localhost, custom-errors

i have a customer order details page. When the client clicks on the "view details" link, it will be redirected to "http://localhost:1958/Admin/OrderDetails.aspx?Id=1"

However, when i(as a customer) try to change the ID for example to "2", it still shows the details of the customer having ID#2 (which is the order details of other customer). What i want is to have an error like 404 error when a customer tries to change the ID in the localhost.

this is my orderdetailscustomer page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Id"]))
        {
            string TransactionNo = Request.QueryString["Id"];

            ucCustomerOrder11.TransactionNoText = TransactionNo;
        }

            ucCustomerOrder11.IsAuthorizedToAddStatus = false;

        }
    }
```

this is the code inside my usercontrol page:

```
public partial class ucCustomerOrder1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public bool CanIUpdateStatus;

    public string TransactionNoText
    {
        get { return txtTransactionNo.Text; }
        set { txtTransactionNo.Text = value; }
    }
    public bool IsAuthorizedToAddStatus
    {
        set { CanIUpdateStatus = value; }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["IslandGasAdmin/ST"] == null)
            {
                txtTransactionNo.ReadOnly = true;
                btnGo.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                txtTransactionNo.ReadOnly = false;
                btnGo.Visible = true;
            }
            if (txtTransactionNo.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                ShowOrderDetails(rblOrderDetails.SelectedValue, Convert.ToInt32(txtTransactionNo.Text));
            }
            else
            {
                rblOrderDetails.Visible = false;
                Panel1.Visible = false;
                Panel2.Visible = false;
                Panel3.Visible = false;
                Panel4.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ShowOrderDetails(string PanelId, int OrderNo)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = false;
        Panel2.Visible = false;
        Panel3.Visible = false;
        Panel4.Visible = false;
        rblOrderDetails.Visible = false;

        if (IsOrderNoValid(OrderNo))
        {
            rblOrderDetails.Visible = true;
            if (PanelId == "1")
            {
                ShoppingCart k = new ShoppingCart
                {
                    Flag = OrderNo
                };
                DataTable dtCustomerDetails = k.GetOrderList();

                if (dtCustomerDetails.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Panel1.Visible = true;
                    lblCustomerName.Text = Convert.ToString(dtCustomerDetails.Rows[0]["CustomerName"]);
                    lblCustomerPhoneNo.Text = Convert.ToString(dtCustomerDetails.Rows[0]["CustomerPhoneNo"]);
                    lblCustomerEmailID.Text = Convert.ToString(dtCustomerDetails.Rows[0]["CustomerEmailID"]);
                    lblTotalPrice.Text = String.Format("{0:#,000.00}",dtCustomerDetails.Rows[0]["TotalPrice"]);
                    lblTotalProducts.Text = Convert.ToString(dtCustomerDetails.Rows[0]["TotalProducts"]);
                    txtCustomerAddress.Text = Convert.ToString(dtCustomerDetails.Rows[0]["CustomerAddress"]);
                    lblPaymentMethod.Text = Convert.ToString(dtCustomerDetails.Rows[0]["PaymentMethod"]);
                }
            }
            if (PanelId == "2")
            {
                Panel2.Visible = true;

                ShoppingCart k = new ShoppingCart()
                {
                    Flag = OrderNo
                };

                dlProducts.DataSource = k.GetTransactionDetails(); ;
                dlProducts.DataBind();
            }
            if (PanelId == "3")
            {
                Panel3.Visible = true;
                DropDownStatus.Visible = CanIUpdateStatus;
                txtStatus.Visible = false;
                //txtStatus.Visible = CanIUpdateStatus;
                btnAdd.Visible = CanIUpdateStatus;
                GetSetOrderStatus(0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Panel4.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    private bool IsOrderNoValid(int OrderNo)
    {
        ShoppingCart k = new ShoppingCart
        {
            Flag = OrderNo
        };
        DataTable dtCustomerDetails = k.GetOrderList();

        if (dtCustomerDetails.Rows.Count > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    private void GetSetOrderStatus(int Flag)
    {
        ShoppingCart k = new ShoppingCart
        {
            OrderStatus = DropDownStatus.SelectedValue,
            OrderNo = txtTransactionNo.Text,
            Flag = Flag
        };
        DataTable dt = k.GetSetOrderStatus();

        gvOrderStatus.DataSource = dt;
        gvOrderStatus.DataBind();
        //txtStatus.Text = string.Empty;
        //DropDownStatus.SelectedValue = string.Empty;

    }
```

Comment: Please calrify what you want to do. The admin should not have access to view the customer with ID=2, or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the issue is with the client side. When a client clicks on the view details: it shows "http://localhost:1958/Admin/OrderDetails.aspx?Id=1". if the client changes the id = 2, it still shows the details(from other customer).

Comment: Then I would say you have 2 options:
1. Implement proper authorize handling
2. Quick and dirty version, where you look in your OrderDetails.aspx if the logged in customer view the correct customer. If not, redirect to a 404.aspx.

By the way, a 403 forbidden is proplably more appropiate.

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod : you should have that validation on Code side.

Comment: @SagarR can you give me a good idea sir?

Comment: @Hypnobrew i go with the quick version. can you site an example sir pls?

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod : i assuming that you have already defined roles as you are already saying that you have admin and customer two different types of users,so as per you question you don't want to show record which holds ID=2,so what you can do is,on load event of page put simple condition whether the current customer can access this ID or not,if yes than show your page else redirect to your custom page.

Comment: have another problem @SagarR. one customer has multiple order id's. for example customer has 5 orders. (Id 1,3,5,10,11)

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod : thats not an issue,you can check something like,Find all OrderId (IE CustId=2 can have OrderID = {1,3,5,7}),but all that orderID will have same Customer.So you just have to check If Current CustomerID holds the given OrderID or not?

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod : does that worked for you?

Comment: no idea how to do it. will edit the question and include my code @SagarR

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod : Thats great...some code will make question more rich.

Comment: edited sir @SagarR hope you could help me out

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod : please check answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting your usercontrol page exactly,but the condition I have changed as per previous communication,so you can 
You can try something this,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         int UserId= Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"].ToString());    //Here I am assuming you are taking CustomerID in some session.
         int OrderID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Id"]); //Your orderID

         int CustId= "Query : Select CustomerID from sometable where OrderID=Your Above OrderID"   //Now Query to get CustomerID from Current OrderID

        if (UserId==CustId) //Check condition
        {

            ucCustomerOrder11.TransactionNoText = UserId;
            ucCustomerOrder11.IsAuthorizedToAddStatus = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ucCustomerOrder11.IsAuthorizedToAddStatus = false;
            Response.Redirect("CustomPage.aspx"); // for show message regarding not authorised access.
        }
    }
```

Comment: isauthorized to add status is on a different thing sir.